# Make a SQL select query for each item in the list?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have a student table like this:

| ID | Name | Major | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Math | F |
| 2 | Bob | Biology | M |
| 3 | Candice | Econ | F |

And I have a list of data like this:

```
names=["Alice,"Bob","Candice"] majors=["Math","Biology","Econ"] genders="["F","M","F"]
```

I want to return the first ID that matches all three columns for all entries in
the list
(e.g. `SELECT id FROM students WHERE name='Alice' AND major = "Math" AND gender = "F"`).

Is there a way to get all of the data I need with just one SQL query instead of
having to make a separate query for each item in the list?

```
SELECT id FROM students WHERE name='Alice' AND major = "Math" AND gender = "F" ;
SELECT id FROM students WHERE name='Bob' AND major = "Biology" AND gender = "M" ;
SELECT id FROM students WHERE name='Candice' AND major = "Econ" AND gender = "F" ;
```

I can only get the IDs by making three separate queries. I want to combine these into one. I tried using `IN`, but that only seems to work when you only need 1 column to match. In this case, I need the name, major, and gender to match the entry in the list.

Comment: *the first ID that matches* What is "the first"? For what ordering, by what expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple columns in a list that you test with `IN`.

```
SELECT id
FROM students
WHERE (name, major, gender) IN (
    ('Alice', 'Math', 'F'), 
    ('Bob', 'Biology', 'M'), 
    ('Candice', 'Econ', 'F'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in Postgres using UNNEST and CTEs. If you dont want to use an CTE then you can use a subquery instead of a CTE.

```
create table students (
  id serial,
  name varchar,
  major varchar,
  gender varchar
);

insert into students (name,major, gender) 
values ('Alice', 'Math', 'F'),
  ('Bob', 'Biology', 'M'),
  ('Candice', 'Econ', 'F');
  

WITH CTE0 AS (
  SELECT 
    UNNEST('{"Alice", "Bob", "Candice"}'::varchar[]) as name,
    UNNEST('{"Math","Biology","Econ"}'::varchar[]) as major,
    UNNEST('{"F","M","F"}'::varchar[]) as gender
) SELECT S.*
  FROM students S
  INNER JOIN CTE0 ON CTE0.name = S.name AND CTE0.major=S.major AND CTE0.gender = S.gender
```

In the above I am using `unnest` to expand array into a set of rows, using multiple unnest will return a set of rows, each row is a records.

**Note:** Make sure that all the arrays in Unnest contains the same length.

Edit: I didn't know UNNEST is a postgres only function and mysql doesn't have this function.